# Check if a word appears at least twice in a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a list:

```
[('a','Organization'),('b','Organization'),('c','Person'),('d','Location'),('e','Organization')]
```

How could I know whether the word `'Organization'` appears at least twice in this list ?

**I also get another solution:**

```
Counter([c for (w,c) in list])['ORGANIZATION'] >= 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a generator comprehension and `sum` to count the amount of times `'Organization'` appears:

```
l = [('a','Organization'),('b','Organization'),
     ('c','Person'),('d','Location'),('e','Organization')]

sum(1 for i,j in l if j == 'Organization') > 2
# True
```

Comment: why not `for x, y in l if y == 'Organization'`?

Comment: Yeah that also works, but then you have to check if `'Organization'` is in `any` of them

Comment: Isn't `Organization` only the second element of the tuples?

Comment: Actually I think you're right, I assumed it could be in either. Thanks @MohitMotwani !

Comment: Thanks for your help! I also get another solution: if Counter([c for (w,c) in list])['ORGANIZATION'] >= 2:

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
a = [('a','Organization'),('b','Organization'),('c','Person'),('d','Location'),('e','Organization')]
check_tot_appearance = sum(1 for i in a if 'Organization' in i)>=2
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = [('a','Organization'),('b','Organization'),('c','Person'),('d','Location'),('e','Organization')]

sublist = [value[1] for value in list]  # retrieve every second value of each tuple
print(sublist.count('Organization'))  # find occurrences of 'Organization'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `operator.itemgetter`

**Ex:**

```
from operator import itemgetter
data = [('a','Organization'),('b','Organization'),('c','Person'),('d','Location'),('e','Organization')]

print(list(map(itemgetter(1), data)).count("Organization"))
```

**Output:**

```
3
```

Answer (score 0):

use `filter` to check if 'Organsiation' in tuple and the count length if more than twice, it return True

```
a=[('a','Organization'),('b','Organization'),('c','Person'),('d','Location'),('e','Organization')]

print(len(list(filter(lambda x: 'Organization' in x,a)))>=2 )

#output True
```